# What are some advanced caching strategies in redis

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, amazon-elasticache

## Problem

we have a large enterprise e-commerce (laravel) application that uses redis for caching. Our system carries a huge amount of inventory and the number just keeps on growing as we add more stores to our system. We also cache the localization of our system.

However by looking at the redis current items in our AWS Cloudwatch, it's clear that our cache is growing exponentially. This is obviously not sustainable.

[image]

## What we tried

I reached out to AWS support and they gave out this generic and very basic [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Strategies.html) about caching strategies.

I was hoping for more advanced strategies, any ideas?

Comment: There are a number of [eviction policies](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache) in Redis which are also directly supported in ElasticCache Redis. Other than that the obvious solution is to cache less things or for less time

Comment: First all, you'd want to cache frequently needed and non-volatile data. For eviction, there are a number of algorithms such as LRU (least recently used), LFU (least frequently used), TTL (time to live for an item), or even implement your own custom strategy for your specific use case